# php variable variables {}

Tags: php, variables

I need to pass a lot of variables to a PHP class from a database and can't figure out the correct syntax.

This is the class's variable format:

```
$this->SetX('X','Y',15);
```

I have tried these but none work:

```
$var = 'SetX';
$this->{$var} = array('foo','bar',15);
$this->{$var}('foo','bar',15);
$this->{$var} = "'foo','bar',15";
```

But none work, can this be done ??

OK, now understand that this is a method, however the method name and it's associated variables are dynamic and stored in a DB and I therefore need to generate these on the fly.

Comment: are you trying to call the SetX method with the given parameters ?

Comment: call_user_func_array() perhaps??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a method, not an attribute. But the second version would work if you leave out the curly braces:

```
$var = "SetX";
$this->$var("foo", "bar", 15);
```

Comment: Thanks very much:$this->$var("foo", "bar", 15);
 does work. the call_user_func_array also worked

Answer (score 0):

$this->SetX('X','Y',15); is a method, not a variable. You're calling a method of an object, not setting the variable of an object.

Loop your results from the database and keep calling $this->SetX('X','Y',15); and replace X, Y, and 15 with values from your DB.

Comment: Ahh, I see, but I have all of these methods stored in a database and the method name is therefore dynamic as well as it's variables ??

Answer (score -1):

If you want to call a function based on a variable name, you'll have to use `call_user_func` or `call_user_func_array`, like so: `call_user_func_array(array($this, $var), array('X', 'Y', 15));`

Comment: you don't have to use call_user_func for variable methods